# Reading from inFile - Java

Tags: java

I am attempting to read from a file - my code is below:

```
try 
    {
        Scanner inFile = new Scanner (new FileReader("input.txt"));

        while(inFile.hasNextLine()) 
        {
            first = inFile.next();
            second = inFile.next();
            System.out.println("first: " + first);
            System.out.println("second: " + second);

        }

        inFile.close();    

    }
    catch(FileNotFoundException exception)
    {
        System.out.println("Unable to locate file");
    }
```

The file text is:

```
Fred 10
John 13
Bob
Jill 43
```

Because some lines do not contain any text the program crashes. For example, this program crashes when it tries to give "second" a value in the third line - the one containing Bob.

How can I create an if value exists? Or ignore if no value?

Comment: Call `inFile.hasNext()` to see if there is another token.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use useDelimiter function and iterate the line again

```
while(inFile.hasNextLine()) 
            {

                Scanner sc = new Scanner(inFile.nextLine());
                sc.useDelimeter(" ");
                while(sc.hasNext())
                    System.out.println(sc.next());

            }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your program is (incorrectly) assuming that there *are* two values per line always. If that's not true, you'll need to consider that case. A way could be (untested):

```
while(inFile.hasNextLine()) {
  first = inFile.next();
  if (!inFile.hasNext()) {
    continue; // ignore this line
  }
  second = inFile.next();
  ...
}
```

Unrelated to your question: you are incorrectly closing inFile. [This info](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) may come in handy.